# MVVM light or MVVM cross in xamarin portable

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I have to convert a UWP app to be compatible on all OS. I am creating cross platform- Native portable xamarin project for this and not using xamarn.forms and whose core is a PCL. I have used MVVM light in my existing UWP app. I see that mvvm light is not compatible in xamarin.touch. What should I go ahead with? Can I use mvvm light for windows phone project and mvvm cross for others? or Should I use mvvm cross for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think MvvM light is not working with Xamarin.iOS? 
MvvMLight is available for

- Windows Presentation Foundation (3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.5.1)
- Silverlight (4 and 5)
- Windows Phone (7.1, 8, 8.1 Silverlight, 8.1 RT)
- Windows Store (8, 8.1)
- Xamarin Android
- Xamarin iOS
- Xamarin Forms

http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/10/announcing-mvvm-light-v5-for-windows-and-xamarin/

So you can use MvvM light or MvvMCross. I'd not recommend to use both frameworks in one project.

Comment: If I want to choose any one MVVM approach then how can I pick any approach and on what basis?